# fprintf segfault error despite strings printing independently

Tags: c, printf

I am getting a strange segfault on the last case.  Valgring states illegal memory access

```
    fprintf(stderr, "Print %s \n", primary_key->name);
    fprintf(stderr, "Print %s \n", table->table);
    fprintf(stderr, "Print %s \n ", db->table); 

    fprintf(stderr, "Print %s\\%s \n", db->table, table->table);
```

The first 3 statements work absolutely fine, but as soon as I try to access the two together, I get a segfault. Any thoughts? (this is actual code, there's nothing in between) I'm new to C, so don't necessarily know in detail how fprintf works.

The valgrind error is:

Print 345 
Print foo 
Print test

==19994== Invalid read of size 1

==19994==    at 0x5EF53B1: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1630)

==19994==    by 0x5EF81A3: buffered_vfprintf (vfprintf.c:2313)

==19994==    by 0x5EF2BDD: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1316)

==19994==    by 0x5EFD836: fprintf (fprintf.c:33)

==19994==    by 0x5E95E9: ...

==19994==  Address 0x4 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd

==19994==

Comment: What does valgrind say? (the full message)

Comment: Humor us. What is `table` defined as (all of them, both the object and two members, but especially the latter).

Comment: Both defined as part of an Item struct, and a char* field.
(Edited to reflect valgrind output)

Comment: Really need more of the context - as far as I can see, the problem must either be in `table` or `db` (either the pointers or what they point to) or else in some other code somewhere else. One annoying thing with "undefined behaviour" - it can seem to work, but leave things in a bad state that causes something else to fail in a way that's hard to predict and extremely frustrating to debug. Therefore, check that all buffers are allocated correctly, all strings null-terminated, there's no dangling pointers etc etc.

Comment: Either the char* was freed, one (or both) item structs was(were) freed, or combinations therein, or were never valid to begin with. I'd trace back the source of those and find where they were last touched and possibly released. Chances are your printf is consuming the memory they once had with buffer-space due to the multi format specifier, but as Steve said, UB is a ruthless wench at times. Good luck.

Comment: nothing much can be guessed unless u provide more info on code like r u freeing the variables somewhere else or is any other module, thread updating the same memory location.